# sec:authorize doesn't work for newly added users

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have done a spring security with databbases tutorial by mkyong. Everything was working fine, but now when i'm  adding a new user to users and user_roles table and then logining on these accounts the sec:authorize with `access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"` doesn't work and any data in sec:authorize tag isn't displayed.

There are spring-security settings

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- enable use-expressions -->
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

        <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />

        <!-- access denied page -->
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />

        <form-login 
            login-page="/login" 
            default-target-url="/welcome" 
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout"  />
        <!-- enable csrf protection -->
        <csrf/>
    </http>

    <!-- Select users and user_roles from database -->
    <authentication-manager>
      <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
          users-by-username-query=
            "select username,password, enabled from users where username=?"
          authorities-by-username-query=
            "select username, role from user_roles where username =?  " />
      </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

And there is mentioned code with sec:authorize block

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')">
        <!-- For login user -->
        <c:url value="/j_spring_security_logout" var="logoutUrl" />
        <form action="${logoutUrl}" method="post" id="logoutForm">
            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                value="${_csrf.token}" />
        </form>
        <script>
            function formSubmit() {
                document.getElementById("logoutForm").submit();
            }
        </script>

        <c:if test="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name != null}">
            <h2>
                User : ${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name} | <a
                    href="javascript:formSubmit()"> Logout</a>
            </h2>
        </c:if>


    </sec:authorize>
```

I can check if user is logged in in Controller, but sec:authorize doesn't work in session in which newly created user is logged in:

```
//this works
if (!(auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
            UserDetails userDetail = (UserDetails) auth.getPrincipal();
            model.addObject("username", userDetail.getUsername());
        }
```

Comment: Roles are cached in the session, is that what you mean?

Comment: No, i just mean that when user is logged in the sec:authorize doesn't work and the content of that block isn't displayed @holmis83

Comment: What do you get if you print the roles, e.g. `<sec:authentication property="principal.authorities"/>` ?

Comment: USER_ROLE should be ROLE_USER. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

As  @holmis83 suggested, i have added

```
<sec:authentication property="principal.authorities"/>
```

To check content of role column in user_roles table in my db. It turned out that i was saving the roles as 'USER_ROLE' and should be 'ROLE_USER'. I have updated the users roles to proper values and now everything works well.